# Getting the "Open link in a new tab" property from a WordPress menu item

Tags: wordpress, timber

In a typical menu item loop is there something like `item.target` when setting the 'Open link in a new tab' option?

I see the issue has been brought up before and is now [available in Timber V2](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1629) but is there a way to get it working in available in [Timber version 1.0](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1629)?

```
{% for item in menu.items %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.link }}" target="{{ item.target }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what version of Timber are you using?

Comment: Using the latest WP Plugin version of Timber V1.19.1

Comment: Im testing on `v1.19.1` with the Timber starter theme and `{{ item.target }}` is working for me.

Comment: When I `print_r` the menu in the`$context` I can see that `target` is part of the menu item so should be able to access it like your example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works in `Timber v1.19.1` `Twig v1.42.5`

```
{% for item in menu.items %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ item.link }}"
           target="{{ item.meta( '_menu_item_target' ) ? item.meta( '_menu_item_target' ) : '_self' }}">
              {{ item.title }}
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```